# Running Mathpix Snipping Tool on aarch64 Linux

Tags: arm, emulation

The software in question is [Mathpix Snipping Tool](https://download.mathpix.com/linux/Mathpix_Snipping_Tool-x86_64.v03.00.0065.AppImage), a really good OCR software for converting images of math equations into LaTeX code, which I use daily.

My hardware is a Chromebook running Ubuntu LTS 22.04 on Crostini.

I have tried:

- qemu-x86_64, with result `qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory`;
- FEX-Emu, with result `[4778:4778:20221024,035902.391183:ERROR scoped_ptrace_attach.cc:27] ptrace: Operation not permitted (1) Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`;
- box64, with result

```
Dynarec for ARM64, with extension: ASIMD AES CRC32 PMULL ATOMICS PageSize:4096
Box64 with Dynarec v0.1.9 58cdb1b built on Oct 23 2022 06:56:54
Using default BOX64_LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ./:lib/:lib64/:x86_64/:bin64/:libs64/
Using default BOX64_PATH: ./:bin/
Counted 41 Env var
Looking for ./Mathpix_Snipping_Tool-x86_64.v03.00.0065.AppImage
Rename process to "Mathpix_Snipping_Tool-x86_64.v03.00.0065.AppImage"
Using native(wrapped) libdl.so.2
Using native(wrapped) libc.so.6
Using native(wrapped) ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Using native(wrapped) libpthread.so.0
Using native(wrapped) librt.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libz.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libfuse.so.2
Dynarec for ARM64, with extension: ASIMD AES CRC32 PMULL ATOMICS PageSize:4096
Box64 with Dynarec v0.1.9 58cdb1b built on Oct 23 2022 06:56:54
Using default BOX64_LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ./:lib/:lib64/:x86_64/:bin64/:libs64/
Using default BOX64_PATH: ./:bin/
Counted 45 Env var
Looking for /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/AppRun
Rename process to "AppRun"
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libsentry.so
Using native(wrapped) libX11.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libxcb.so.1
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5WebEngine.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5X11Extras.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5QmlModels.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5WebChannel.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Network.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Core.so.5
Using native(wrapped) libGL.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libpthread.so.0
Using emulated /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libm.so.6
Using emulated /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libc.so.6
Using native(wrapped) ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Using native(wrapped) librt.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libcurl.so.4
Using native(wrapped) libdl.so.2
Using native(wrapped) libz.so.1
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/lib/libicui18n.so.56
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/lib/libicuuc.so.56
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/lib/libicudata.so.56
Using native(wrapped) libgthread-2.0.so.0
Using native(wrapped) libglib-2.0.so.0
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/lib/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5
Using native(wrapped) libsmime3.so
Using native(wrapped) libnss3.so
Using native(wrapped) libnssutil3.so
Using native(wrapped) libplds4.so
Using native(wrapped) libplc4.so
Using native(wrapped) libnspr4.so
Using native(wrapped) libresolv.so.2
Using native(wrapped) libXcomposite.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libXdamage.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libXext.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libXau.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libXdmcp.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libXfixes.so.3
Using native(wrapped) libXrender.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libXrandr.so.2
Using native(wrapped) libfreetype.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libexpat.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libfontconfig.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libX11-xcb.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libxcb-dri3.so.0
Using native(wrapped) libXcursor.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libXi.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libXtst.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libxkbcommon.so.0
Using native(wrapped) libdbus-1.so.3
Using native(wrapped) libasound.so.2
Using native(wrapped) libgssapi_krb5.so.2
Error: Global Symbol GSS_C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE not found, cannot apply R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT @0x7906257b80 ((nil)) in /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libQt5Network.so.5
Dynarec for ARM64, with extension: ASIMD AES CRC32 PMULL ATOMICS PageSize:4096
Box64 with Dynarec v0.1.9 58cdb1b built on Oct 23 2022 06:56:54
Using default BOX64_LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ./:lib/:lib64/:x86_64/:bin64/:libs64/
Using default BOX64_PATH: ./:bin/
Counted 45 Env var
Looking for /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/crashpad_handler
argv[1]="--no-rate-limit"
argv[2]="--database=/home/sayako/.local/share/Mathpix/Mathpix Snipping Tool/logs/sentry"
argv[3]="--metrics-dir=/home/sayako/.local/share/Mathpix/Mathpix Snipping Tool/logs/sentry"
argv[4]="--url=https://o143679.ingest.sentry.io:443/api/5726799/minidump/?sentry_client=sentry.native/0.4.8&sentry_key=affbd79da01c4144931f75efc8fe55f2"
argv[5]="--attachment=/home/sayako/.local/share/Mathpix/Mathpix Snipping Tool/logs/sentry/b9e43b74-4bbf-4931-a4f2-75fdd6575301.run/__sentry-event"
argv[6]="--attachment=/home/sayako/.local/share/Mathpix/Mathpix Snipping Tool/logs/sentry/b9e43b74-4bbf-4931-a4f2-75fdd6575301.run/__sentry-breadcrumb1"
argv[7]="--attachment=/home/sayako/.local/share/Mathpix/Mathpix Snipping Tool/logs/sentry/b9e43b74-4bbf-4931-a4f2-75fdd6575301.run/__sentry-breadcrumb2"
argv[8]="--initial-client-fd=7"
argv[9]="--shared-client-connection"
Rename process to "crashpad_handler"
Using native(wrapped) libz.so.1
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libssl.so.1.1
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
Using native(wrapped) libpthread.so.0
Using native(wrapped) libdl.so.2
Using native(wrapped) libc.so.6
Using native(wrapped) ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Using native(wrapped) librt.so.1
Using emulated /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
Using native(wrapped) libm.so.6
Using emulated /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb-icccm.so.4
Using native(wrapped) libxcb-image.so.0
Using native(wrapped) libxcb-shm.so.0
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb-util.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libxcb-keysyms.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libxcb-randr.so.0
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb-render-util.so.0
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb-render.so.0
Using native(wrapped) libxcb-shape.so.0
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb-sync.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libxcb-xfixes.so.0
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb-xinerama.so.0
Using emulated /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb-xkb.so.1
Using native(wrapped) libxkbcommon-x11.so.0
Error: PltResolver: Symbol xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_unchecked(ver 0: xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_unchecked) not found, cannot apply R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT 0x78e7df8320 (0x78e7ad7ee6) in /tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
Stop waiting for remaining thread 5133
Stop waiting for remaining thread 5139
Stop waiting for remaining thread 5141
sayako@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Workspace/Software$ 5135|SIGBUS @0x6497f82c (???(/tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/crashpad_handler+0x6497f82c)) (x64pc=0x7b28a246b8//tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libssl.so.1.1:"???", rsp=0x7b28246d90, stack=0x7b27a48000:0x7b28248000 own=(nil) fp=0x7b28246d98), for accessing 0x7b28a246b8 (code=2/prot=7), db=(nil)((nil):(nil)/(nil):(nil)/???:clean, hash:0/0) handler=0x40a580
RSP-0x20:0x0000000000000000 RSP-0x18:0x0000007b28246d88 RSP-0x10:0x0000007b289d4888 RSP-0x08:0x0000007b28246d98
RSP+0x00:0x00000000000300c0 RSP+0x08:0x0000007b28246da0 RSP+0x10:0x0000000000000000 RSP+0x18:0x00000000004066495135|SIGBUS @0x649b9318 (???(/tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/crashpad_handler+0x649b9318)) (x64pc=0x7b28a246b8//tmp/.mount_Mathpiskr7Oa/usr/bin/../lib/libssl.so.1.1:"???", rsp=0x7b28246d90, stack=0x7b27a48000:0x7b28248000 own=(nil) fp=0x7b28246d98), for accessing 0x7b28a246bf (code=2/prot=7), db=(nil)((nil):(nil)/(nil):(nil)/???:clean, hash:0/0) handler=0x40a580
RSP-0x20:0x0000000000000000 RSP-0x18:0x0000007b28246d88 RSP-0x10:0x0000007b289d4888 RSP-0x08:0x0000007b28246d98
RSP+0x00:0x00000000000300c0 RSP+0x08:0x0000007b28246da0 RSP+0x10:0x0000000000000000 RSP+0x18:0x00000000004066495135|Double SIGBUS (code=2, pc=0x649b9318, addr=0x7b28a246bf)!
```

I'm looking for some suggestions on making one of the above already-tried programs to work, another emulator to try, or something crazy like recompiling to aarch64 without the source code.

The developers of this app ghosted me after asking for an aarch64 build. The communiactions are [image]. It will be nice if you join me in bothering them.

---

Update:

[image]

Comment: I don't think calling us to "bother" them helps. We can look at your technical problem, though!

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes please. My discord is Fourier-Deligne Transgirl#3264. I can give you ssh there.

Comment: no. we can look at the problem you describe *here*. We generally keep what we do in the open, so that everyone benefits from the results!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes I know that. I mean I'll give you ssh access and then if you resolve the problem I'm surely going to write them here.

Comment: no. That's not how that works. If you want me to administrate your system, you'll have to pay full consulting rates, and a minimum contract setup fee. I help as good as I can, like everyone else here, for free by answering questions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sure. (actually, if you can guarantee to make it work (e.g. by doing reverse engineering magic or so), a fee isn't unacceptable